# Integral inequalities.

Tags: integration

If f(t) is non-negative and bounded function, then by Schwartz inequality, we have $(\int\limits_0^tf(s)ds)^2 \leq t\int\limits_0^tf^2(s)ds$.

Now my questions are,

(i) is there any possibility to express the integral $\left(\int\limits_0^tf(s)ds\right)^{2n}$ as above?

or

(ii) can we write the (i) as $\left(\int\limits_0^tf(s)ds\right)^{2n} \leq t^{2n-1}\int\limits_0^tf^{2n}(s)ds$?

Is there any articles or books, which discuss this kind of integral inequalities?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives an inequality, not an identity. $$\left(\int_{0}^{t}1\cdot f(s)\,ds\right)^2\color{red}{\leq} t\int_{0}^{t}f^2(s)\,ds.$$

Comment: thank you. Actually my question means inequality but not identity. just typing mistake. sorry

Answer (score 0):

The general concept you need is Hölder's inequality

$$
\int\limits_a^bf(x)\cdot g(x)\, dx \leq \left(\int\limits_a^b|f(x)|^{p}\, dx\right)^{\frac1p}\left(\int\limits_a^b|q(x)|^{q}\, dx\right)^{\frac1q}, 
$$
where $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$.

---

For your case $g(x)=1$, $p=2n$.

$$
\left(\int\limits_0^tf(x)\cdot 1\, dx\right)^{2n}
\leq \left(\left(\int\limits_0^t|f(x)|^{2n}\, dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2n}}\left(\int\limits_0^t1^{\frac{2n}{2n-1}}\, dx\right)^{\frac{2n-1}{2n}}\right)^{2n}
= \\ t^{2n-1}\int\limits_0^t|f(x)|^{2n}\, dx.
$$